# Is there an add-on that will open IE9's last browsing session to all the same open tabs automatically?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, internet-explorer-9

I know Chrome and Firefox can do this, but Internet Explorer can't. This sometimes works if I select "reopen last browsing session" but it's not reliable enough. Anyone know of an add-on that will do what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open IE9
2. Open a new Tab
3. At the bottom left there is are 2 links 
   3.1 Reopen closed tabs (With a drop down to select a specific one)
   3.2 Reopen last session
   [image]
   That's it, its inbuilt.

Comment: Is this supposed to always work? It seems very hit or miss for me.

Comment: Yup works for me. Does not work after you close an empty window though. But isn't that how its supposed to work? :)

Comment: @IUnknown it seems to be the way MS intended it to work - that doesn't change the fact that it's subfunctional and sometimes (read: "every time you didn't ***manually*** select reopen last session") is very inconvenient.

Comment: Is there a way to make this automatically? Just like Chrome or FF do.

Answer (score 1):

`tools - reopen last browsing session` this restores all open tabs from the prior browsing session. No need for an add-on

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an Add-On.

How about getting back further in browsing sessions history?

It's not always exactly the last session that you'd need to recover, for there may have been an accidental page opened by another application after your desired last actual session crashed. It's not that straight forward issue after all, and that's why Firefox has "Session Manager" add-on, with sessions history reaching back multiple sessions. It doesn't take much disk space or computing power to save links of sessions, but is a great help when you're facing problems with your computer and need to restart computer or browser more than often for one reason or another.